# Query builder fetch data in cakephp 3.2

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.2

I am using this below code to sum up all my wallet balance .

```html
$query = $this->Wallets->find();
$query->select([
    'count' => $query->func()->count('id'), 
    'total_price' => $query->func()->sum('amount')
])
->where(['status' => 4, 'user_id' => $user_id]);
pj($query);
echo $query->total_price;
exit;
```

out put of `pj($query);`

```html
[
    {
        "count": 2,
        "total_price": 700
    }
]
```

Here i have tried to get single individual value using  below query

```html
echo $query->total_price;
```

I am not getting it.
What is the proper syntax ,plz suggest me.
Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = $this->Wallets->find();
$query->select([
    'count' => $query->func()->count('id'), 
    'total_price' => $query->func()->sum('amount')
])
->where(['status' => 4, 'user_id' => $user_id]);
debug($query);

// loop your results
foreach($query as $result){
   echo $result->total_price;
}

// or
$query->toArray();
echo $query[0]->total_price;
echo $query[1]->total_price;
...
exit;
```

Comment: Yes the foreach one is working ,i am getting exact result .
Second one not working (answer in or).

Comment: Ok .thank you ,i got my answer.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5):

add `first()` to your query, see the [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#selecting-a-single-row-from-a-table)

```
$query->select([
    'count' => $query->func()->count('id'), 
    'total_price' => $query->func()->sum('amount')
])
->where(['status' => 4, 'user_id' => $user_id]);

$wallet = $query->first();

debug($wallet);

debug($wallet->total_price);
```

Comment: Not getting the result.

Comment: Add more information: what do you get? What query is generated? what you get when you `debug($query)`?

Comment: Yes degug($query) returning result ,but   debug($query->total_price) ,this one throwing error.i am not getting the single individual value.