# Cakephp 3 : Sum a single field without using foreach

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using cakephp 3. Here I need sum a field, I already done it.

```
//mobile recharge total balance
$user_balance = $this->Users->find();
$user_balance
->select(['sum' => $user_balance->func()->sum('Users.balance')])
->first();
foreach ($user_balance as $balance) {
    $this->set("user_balance", $balance->sum);
}
```

Here I have used first(), but why still it's returning an object. Is it possible to get direct sum or array. Here I don't want to use foreach.

Comment: Check it,is this your requirement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query builder fetch data in cakephp 3.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37268510/query-builder-fetch-data-in-cakephp-3-2)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```html
$query = $this->Models->find('all'); //fetch the record

$res = $query->select(['total_sum' =>$query->func()->sum('the_field_you_need')])->first(); //perform the sum operation 
$total = $res->total_sum; your total sum result
```

```html
$user_balance = $this->Users->find();
$res =$user_balance->select(['sum' => $user_balance->func()->sum('Users.balance')])->first();
$total = $res->sum; //your total sum result
```

Comment: No, It's not working. Getting notice Undefined property: Cake\ORM\Query::$sum

Comment: I am happy to help you :) :) :) :)